# mysql insert current date+ more days

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hi I have this problem and I have tryed all solutions I could find with DATE_ADD and more suff like this. So here is my code..

```
$create_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if (md5($_POST['norobot']) == $_SESSION['randomnr2'])   
{ 
    if ((strlen($usern) >= 5) && (strlen($pass) >= 5)&&(strlen($email) >= 12)&&(strlen($idcard)==7))
    {
        $usr = mysql_query("Select * from account.account where login='$usern'");
        $ema = mysql_query("Select * from account.account where email='$email'");

        if ((mysql_num_rows($usr)==1)|| (mysql_num_rows($ema)==1))
        {
            echo error("Cont sau email utilizate.Incercati altele sau click <a href='index.php?page=recuperare-pw'>aici</a> pentru recuperare parola.");
        }
        else
        {   
            if ($_POST['read'] == "checked")
            {
                $rand = rand(99999,9999999999);
                $cod_activ = md5($rand);
                //$cod_activ= "1";
                mysql_query("Insert into account.account (Login,Password,Real_name,Social_id,Email,status,create_time,gold_expire,silver_expire,safebox_expire,autoloot_expire,fish_mind_expire,marriage_fast_expire,money_drop_rate_expire,coins,web_aktiviert) values('$usern',password('$pass'),'$name','$idcard','$email','OK','$create_time','2022-12-31 12:00:00','2022-12-31 12:00:00','2022-12-31 12:00:00','2022-12-31 12:00:00','2022-12-31 12:00:00','2022-12-31 12:00:00','2022-12-31 12:00:00','0','$cod_activ')") or die(mysql_error());
                echo succes('Cont creat cu succes.Va puteti loga acum!');
```

Instead of `2022-12-31 12:00:00` I want to add current date + 30 days any help please? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL `DATE_ADD` would work.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Your Query would be:

```
mysql_query("Insert into account.account (Login,Password,Real_name,Social_id,Email,status,create_time,gold_expire,silver_expire,safebox_expire,autoloot_expire,fish_mind_expire,marriage_fast_expire,money_drop_rate_expire,coins,web_aktiviert) values('$usern',password('$pass'),'$name','$idcard','$email','OK','$create_time',DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY),'0','$cod_activ')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Note: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in future releases, Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

**UPDATE**

Use `CURRENT_TiMESTAMP` instead of `CURDATE()` in case you need date time.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Well thanks for answer, but I have found another solution $bonus_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+ 7 day"));  and then insert intro db $bonus_time, well I will upgrade my game website if I will keep it in future. and I could not use CURDATE sice I need full time.